# Ubuntu installed by copying system files does not boot

Tags: 18.04, backup

I tried to move an existing Ubuntu installation to a new partition by copying all files while running from LiveCD. In the end, the new system gets stuck at boot process.

### What did I do

1. Booted LiveCD.
2. Mounted both old and new partitions.
3. Used something like `cp -a /mnt/old_root/* /mnt/new_root` to copy the files, which supposedly preserves file metadata. (Maybe I should try [other options](https://superuser.com/q/307541/920830))
4. Corrected `/etc/fstab` on the new system.
5. Reinstalled GRUB by following [these steps](https://superuser.com/a/376471/920830) in the first attempt and [these steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) in the second attempt.
6. Tried to boot the new system.
7. Fixed [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/1094776/28667) but it was not the cause.

**UPD:** I tried to do the same steps on a newly installed system and got the same result.

Unimportant details:

1. I run the system in VirtualBox Version 6.0.5 r128870
2. The system is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS; Linux 4.15.0-45-generic.

### What did I get

- The system boot begins.
- It looks like the system successfully mounts `/` and `/home`. (When there was a mistake in `/etc/fstab` the system quickly dropped to maintenance shell)
- **The system boot gets stuck in the animated splash screen.**
- If I hide the splash screen, I can see the same services fail to start over and over again. The system almost does not utilise CPU or storage.
  [image: Boot console screenshot]
- I can boot to recovery mode from GRUB.
- The first error messages from journal:

```
2019-02-19T18:29:37+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Reached target Sockets.
2019-02-19T18:29:37+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Reached target Basic System.
2019-02-19T18:29:37+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
2019-02-19T18:29:37+0000 hostname dbus-daemon[1104]: dbus[1104]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
2019-02-19T18:31:07+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to get initial list of names: Connection timed out
2019-02-19T18:31:07+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to set up API bus: Connection timed out
2019-02-19T18:31:07+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Error occured during D-Bus APIs initialization: Connection timed out
2019-02-19T18:31:07+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
2019-02-19T18:31:07+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
2019-02-19T18:31:07+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
2019-02-19T18:31:07+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
2019-02-19T18:31:07+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
2019-02-19T18:31:07+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
2019-02-19T18:31:07+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Starting LSB: OpenIPMI Driver init script...
2019-02-19T18:31:07+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
2019-02-19T18:31:08+0000 hostname avahi-daemon[1138]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 115) and group 'avahi' (GID 122).
2019-02-19T18:31:08+0000 hostname avahi-daemon[1138]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
2019-02-19T18:31:08+0000 hostname avahi-daemon[1138]: open(/run/avahi-daemon//pid): Permission denied
2019-02-19T18:31:08+0000 hostname avahi-daemon[1138]: Failed to create PID file: Permission denied
```

- Messages like these are repeated every 90 seconds. As I understand, dbus-daemon dies.

```
2019-02-19T20:53:47+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to get initial list of names: Connection timed out
2019-02-19T20:53:47+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to set up API bus: Connection timed out
2019-02-19T20:53:47+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Error occured during D-Bus APIs initialization: Connection timed out
2019-02-19T20:53:47+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
2019-02-19T20:53:47+0000 hostname systemd[1]: dbus.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2019-02-19T20:53:47+0000 hostname systemd[1]: dbus.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2019-02-19T20:53:47+0000 hostname systemd[1]: rsyslog.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
2019-02-19T20:53:47+0000 hostname systemd[1]: whoopsie.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
2019-02-19T20:53:47+0000 hostname systemd[1]: whoopsie.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 7.
2019-02-19T20:53:47+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
2019-02-19T20:53:47+0000 hostname dbus-daemon[4650]: dbus[4650]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
2019-02-19T20:53:47+0000 hostname NetworkManager[4644]: <info>  [1550609627.2637] NetworkManager (version 1.10.6) is starting... (after a restart)
2019-02-19T20:53:47+0000 hostname NetworkManager[4644]: <info>  [1550609627.2641] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: netplan.conf) (etc: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf, 10-ubuntu-fan.conf, default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to get initial list of names: Connection timed out
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to set up API bus: Connection timed out
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Error occured during D-Bus APIs initialization: Connection timed out
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped crash report submission daemon.
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Started crash report submission daemon.
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname systemd[1]: rsyslog.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname systemd[1]: rsyslog.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logging Service.
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname systemd[1]: dbus.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname systemd[1]: dbus.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname whoopsie[4678]: [20:55:17] Could not create lock directory.
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname whoopsie[4678]: [20:55:17] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname whoopsie[4678]: [20:55:17] Could not create lock file: Bad file descriptor
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname whoopsie[4678]: [20:55:17] Could not read directory (13): /var/crash
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname dbus-daemon[4685]: dbus[4685]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
2019-02-19T20:55:17+0000 hostname snapd[1246]: udevmon.go:190: udev monitor observed remove event for unknown device "/sys/dentry(4893:whoopsie.service)"
```

### The question

1. Was `cp -a` expected to work?
2. Where is the difference between the old and the new partition?
3. Should I dig into the boot issue itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank to [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1796959#p1796959), I was able to resolve the problem by executing the following commands in the recovery shell:

```
chown root:root /
chmod 755 /
```

The new system works fine so `cp -a` method is probably OK. The problem was that the root directory had wrong permissions. (As I understand, the directory got its permissions when I formatted the partition; and they obviously stayed the same when I copied the system files inside the directory).

Answer (score 0):

It will cause you more problems with the permissions as you continue to use the system, you should use option to preserve permissions like 
tar cpf -|(cd /newmount;tar xvpf -)
or 
rsync -avzt source/ /dest
(in rsync watch out the trailing slash character)

Comment: Why? `-a` flag (`--archive`) in `cp` should preserve all permissions and other attributes. Only `/` had wrong permissions and I changed that.

Comment: Yeah you are right missed the -a option you mentioned so you will be good enough with this option then.