# Stuck on what I assume is the boot loader screen after reboot

Tags: boot

Recently Installed Ubuntu 22.04, it was working fine until a user tried to install ARM Compiler and debugger drivers, the computer then started acting weird so they rebooted. Now the computer doesn't get past the "bootloader" see the link below for a screenshot. Every line is "okay" except for "Failed to start D-Bus System Message Bus" line then it always leaves off at "unattended-upgrades.service."

Im not sure where to start with troubleshooting this. I have little experience with Linux.

[image]

Comment: There is this [prior question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119856/ubuntu-installed-by-copying-system-files-does-not-boot) which was solved by resetting the permissions of the root folder. For this, you would need a separate bootable USB drive, then mount your Ubuntu drive and change the permissions. Failing to start the D-Bus service is a source of no end of trouble.

Comment: @jos Thanks for your reply, wouldn't the permissions have to have been changed in the first place for them to have to be reset?

Comment: @organic Marble  What would you call that screen that looping to?

Comment: @organic Marble Thanks for Clarifying that, Any idea why it's hanging there?

Comment: Can you boot into recovery mode and run `systemctl status dbus.service` ? Might shed some light if it is possible to do that.

Comment: Yes, the permissions would have to have been changed, but "the computer started acting weird" doesn't rule that out, of course.

Comment: @OrganicMarble let me give that a shot and ill post my findings.

Comment: @Jos Yeah that's what the user told me when I asked him what had happened...Doesn't help anyone really.